# trying to understand the diagonal check of 8 queen problem

Tags: algorithms, computability, c

I was solving the [8 queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) problem and tried to look through the internet for comparison solutions to see how my solutions compared to others. I found one very small bruteforce solution that confused me. And i was wondering if anyone care to explain how the diagonal comparison actually works?

```
void solve(int n, int col, int *hist)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    if (col == n)
    {
        print_solution(n, hist);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < col && !(hist[j] == i || abs(hist[j] - i) == col - j))
            j++;
        if (j < col)
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        hist[col] = i;
        solve(n, col + 1, hist);
        i++;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int hist[8];

    solve(8, 0, hist);
}
```

the code in particular im having problem visualizing is

```
abs(hist[j] - i) == col - j)
```

from what i understand it checks the diagonals but i dont see it.

Comment: The strict programming questions are off-topic here. It might be on-topic at [SO]. By skimming the code, I do not understand what *abs* with two parameters does, it might be good to explain it. Commonly used *abs* takes one parameter.

Comment: sorry i misstyped, was supposed to be a subtraction there. maybe your right, i thought this was the right spot as its more of a algorithm question.

Comment: I did not check the algorithm, but maybe this exploits the fact that `col - row` gives the same result in (southeast-oriented) diagonals: you can see that because moving SE means incrementing both `col` and `row`. Indeed, to see if two cells fall in the same SE-diagonal, it suffices to compute that for both cells.

Comment: @chi yes, i finally got it. its |x1−x2|=|y1−y2|